# Solving recursive sequence using generating functions in a different way

Tags: generating-functions

---

**The problem:** Suppose we have the following recursive series

\begin{cases}
    a_{1}=0 & \\
    a_{n+1} = 8a_{n} + 9 \cdot 10^{n-1}, & n \geq 1
\end{cases}

and we wish to find an explicit expression (formula) for $a_{n}$ using generating functions.

---

I stumbled upon [this similiar question on this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/371714/707163) which is  about a similiar problem to mine but is solved in some different way using quadratics? I am interested in knowing if my problem can be solved in the same way and if so how?

**The following is my way of solving this problem.**

---

Multiply both sides of the equation with $x^{n+1}$

$$a_{n+1} = 8a_{n} + 9 \cdot 10^{n-1} \implies a_{n+1}\color{red}{x^{n+1}} = 8a_{n}\color{red}{x^{n+1}} + 9 \cdot 10^{n-1}\color{red}{x^{n+1}}$$

$$\implies \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n+1}x^{n+1}\ =\ \sum_{n \geq 1} \left(8a_{n}x^{n+1} + 9 \cdot 10^{n-1}x^{n+1}\right)$$

Split up the sums in the right side of the equation and transform the left side to have the form of an ordinary generating function $G(a_{n}; x) = \sum a_{n}x^{n}$.

$$\implies \sum_{n \geq 2} a_{n}x^{n}\ =\ \sum_{n \geq 1} 8a_{n}x^{n+1}\ +\ \sum_{n \geq 1} 9 \cdot 10^{n-1}x^{n+1}$$

Transform the left term in the right side of the equation to also have the form of an OGF and rewrite the right term so it looks like a geometric series.

$$
\implies \sum_{n \geq 2} a_{n}x^{n}\ =
\ 8x\sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n}\ 
+\ 9x^{2}\sum_{n \geq 1} 10^{n-1}x^{n-1}
$$

$$
\implies \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n} - a_{1}x\ =
\ 8x\sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n}\ 
+\ 9x^{2}\sum_{n \geq 1} (10x)^{n-1}
$$

Let $S = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n}$ and keep in mind that $a_{1} = 0$.

$$\implies S = 8xS + 9x^{2} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{1-10x}}_\text{formula for g.series}$$

Solve for $S$

$$\implies S - 8xS = \frac{9x^{2}}{1-10x}$$

$$\implies S = \frac{9x^2}{(1-10x)(1-8x)} \stackrel{PFD}{=} 9x^{2}\left(\frac{A}{1-10x} + \frac{B}{1-8x} \right)$$

---

Solving the partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{1}{(1-10x)(1-8x)} = \frac{A}{1-10x} + \frac{B}{1-8x}$$

Multiply both sides of the equation by the denominator of the left hand side

$$1 = A(1-8x) + B(1-10x)$$

We can now solve for $A$ and $B$ by plugging in "smart" values for $x$. We start by plugging in a value for $x$ such that it makes one of the terms become 0. In this case $x=1/10$ works fine.

$$1 = A\left(1-\frac{8}{10}\right) + B\left(1-\frac{10}{10}\right) \implies 1 = A\frac{2}{10} \implies A = 5$$

Doing the same but with $x=\frac{1}{8}$ gives $B=-4$.

---

Notice how $\frac{5}{1-10x}$ can be written as $5\sum_{n \geq 0} (10x)^{n}$, going from the explicit expression of a geometric series to the actual original series. The same goes for $\frac{4}{1-8x}$.

$$\implies S = 9x^{2} \left(\frac{5}{1-10x} - \frac{4}{1-8x} \right) = 9x^{2}\left(5\sum_{n \geq 0} (10x)^{n} - 4\sum_{n \geq 0} (8x)^{n} \right)$$

Distribute the $9x^{2}$

$$\implies S = 45x^{2} \sum_{n \geq 0} (10x)^{n} - 36x^{2} \sum_{n \geq 0} (8x)^{n}$$

Combine the two sums in the right hand side of the equation

$$\implies \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left(45 \cdot 10^{n}x^{n+2} - 36 \cdot 8^{n}x^{n+2}\right)$$

Modify the right hand side expression to have the form $a_{n}x^{n}$

$$\implies \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n \geq 2} \left(45 \cdot 10^{n-2}x^{n} - 36 \cdot 8^{n-2}x^{n}\right)$$

Since $a_{1} = 0$

$$\implies \sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n \geq 2} a_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n \geq 2} \left(45 \cdot 10^{n-2} - 36 \cdot 8^{n-2}\right)x^{n}$$

Which gives us the final answer, the explicit expression for our above recursive equation.

$$a_{n} = 45 \cdot 10^{n-2} - 36 \cdot 8^{n-2}$$

Comment: Maybe but why generating functions ? It is so much complications... Homegeneous equation is $a_{n+1}=8a_n$ of root $8$ which is different from $10$ in RHS, so $a_n=\alpha\ 8^n +\beta\ 10^n$ and find $\alpha,\beta$ from initial conditions and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a classic alternative: define $b_{n}=10^{n-1}$ then we get the following recurrence relation:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n+1}\\
b_{n+1}
\end{Bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 9\\
0 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n}\\
b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

From here it is easy to see that the explicit formula for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ is the following, using eigen decomposition along the way:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n}\\
b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 9\\
0 & 10
\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{Bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{Bmatrix}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9\\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
8^{n-1} & 0\\
0 & 10^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -9\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{Bmatrix}\\
\\
&=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{9}{2}\cdot\left(10^{n-1}-8^{n-1}\right)\\
10^{n-1}
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$